# Create an ios app to control bike speed maximum MPH/KmPH speed by plus and minus using Hdx command console dvice

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

We want to develop an ios application to monitor and control the bike speed by plus and minus speed from application using Hxd command console device. Hxd command console is BLE enable.

We have not any Sdk for Hxd command device to control the speed of bike by plus and minus the speed from the application.

Please suggest that how we can control the speed of bike using Hxd command console device without any sdk and retrieve the data ( maximum speed, etc ) from the device in the ios application.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is quite broad.  You should edit your pos to ask specific questions regarding your problem and stating what you have tried and the problems you are having. In general terms you will need to use the Core Bluetooth framework on iOS.  If you don't have any documentation on the HxD console characteristics then you will need to reverse-engineer these.  An app such as Light-Blue on the app store may help

Comment: Hxd command console device have features to show the bike speed and control the bike speed by plus and minus. So, we want to control  the speed of bike form the application by plus and minus as hdx command console device done. But we have not any sdk to control the hxd command console from the ios application.

Comment: There's an [Android sdk](http://www.thisisant.com/developer/resources/downloads/) for this but i think there hasn't been any made for iOS till now..

Comment: What u can do is ask thisisant for an sdk or u could make ur own with the help of the android sdk.

Comment: Hi Ahmed Z. Thanks for reply. We want to develop an iOS application to control the bike speed using Hxd command console device. Please suggest any way to integrate that device with ios application to control the speed.

Comment: Is this actually using the ANT+ LEV profile?  in which case BLE is not appropriate you need to use ANT. So for an iphone you need something like Wahoos ANT dongle and then you use there API.